# install jdk on flash drive - Does not give an opportunity to select install location,

Tags: java-7

I have tried in vain to install JDK on a flash drive. I have seen many threads on how to do this, but, I do not see one which addresses my issue. I have JDK on my PC already. No  matter if I Run from the website or save to the desktop or flash drive itself, when I double click the Java icon to install, I do not have an opportunity to select any installation preferences. It just runs the configuration then tells me the files already exist. Even when I save to the flash and click the icon within my flash folder, it still tries to install on the PC. 
Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: This is a valid development question IMO.

Comment: Can't you just manually copy $JDK_HOME from your PC to a folder on the flash drive? This folder contains all the files that the JDK needs - all of the other files (e.g. the java.exe that is added to C:\windows\system32 in a Windows install) are not necessary.

Comment: @ChrisB - that should be an answer I think. It's a good solution.

Comment: Thanks. Tried this but I am unable to locate such a folder in system 32. The only java-type info I find there are 3 files: java, javaw, javaws. I have also checked in both Program Files and Program Files (x86). The recent Java is located in (x86). The install for 1.7.0_4 (Windows 7) creates folders: bin, db, include, jre, lib. I tried copying the bin folder to the flash then clicking the .exe. That simply leads to the command window flashing on the screen for a second.

Answer (score 0):

There's a hacky way to do this that I don't recommend, but apart from copying the files directly to flash drive, this is the only solution I can think of. The Java installer is likely detecting your registry key for the one you already have installed. I don't recommend doing this unless you know what you're doing, but deleting the folders in:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Development Kit

May have it skip the check and just install it. I recommend you write down what you modified in the registry and make sure that you can re-create it before doing this. If this works as I think it will, the Java installer should not detect the other version of Java on your computer, and you should be able to proceed with installation. I still recommend just copying the appropriate directories to your flash drive instead though, Chris B has the right idea.

Note: This is my first answer. I hope I was able to help you! If not, let me know in the comments so I can do my best to get you to the optimal solution you are looking for! :)